# Position of index column in CSV output from pandas data frame

Tags: pandas

I am trying to reposition the index column in the output CSV from pandas `DataFrame.to_csv()`

I can order the non index columns using `columns` but it is unclear how to move the index column.

If i have 2 columns `Name` and `Age` and index i want the columns to come out in the following order in resulting CSV `Name, Age,index`

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` cannot be moved, it is always first column in `DataFrame` or `Series` or `Panel`. But you can copy data from index to another column.

But if need last column created from `index`:

```
df['new_last'] = df.index
```

If need custom position of new column:

```
df.insert(2, 'new', df.index)
```

And last for prevent write index to csv, thanks @Vivek Kalyanarangan:

```
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Comment: and then may be do `index=False` in `to_csv()`